# How to check validity of brackets in wrong order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have to write a method that accepts a string and returns true if the brackets aren't empty, parentheses, and curly brackets close correctly It returns false otherwise.

Here is what I've got:

```
  def empty_brackets?(string)
    %w[ () [] {} ].none?(&string.method(:include?))
  end

  def valid_string?(string)
    match_count = 0

    string.each_char do |c|
      match_count += 1 if [ '[', '{', '(' ].include?(c)
      match_count -= 1 if [ ']', '}', ')' ].include?(c)
    end
    match_count == 0
  end
```

I think my `valid_string?` method is not quite SOLID but most importantly it doesn't pass the test where brackets are in wrong order, like `)somebrackets(`. Could you please advise how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My attempt, pushing all opening brackets in an array, popping closing ones if they match:

```
BRACKET_PAIRS = { '[' => ']', '{' => '}', '(' => ')' }

def valid?(string)
  string.each_char.with_object([]) do |char, bracket_stack|
    if BRACKET_PAIRS.keys.include? char
      bracket_stack << char
    elsif BRACKET_PAIRS.values.include? char
      if char != BRACKET_PAIRS[bracket_stack.last]
        return false
      else
        bracket_stack.pop
      end
    end
  end.empty?
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very efficient version. It uses regex, and pulls out all of your braces (`{}[]()`) into a small array, and then keeps widdling down your pairs until there's nothing left. The second it finds an unmatched pair, it quits and returns false. It also doesn't split the string into a char array, as that will use twice the memory (once for the whole string, and once again for the string split into individual characters).

```
BRACKET_PAIRS = { '{' => '}', '[' => ']', '(' => ')' }
BRACKET_REGEX = /#{BRACKET_PAIRS.to_a.flatten.map { |v| Regexp.escape(v) }.join('|')}/

def valid?(string)
  brackets = string.scan(BRACKET_REGEX)
  while brackets.size > 0
    first = brackets.shift
    last = brackets.pop
    return(false) unless BRACKET_PAIRS[first] == last
  end

  return(true)
end
```

This code will return true if there are no braces at all.

If you don't like that, do this:

```
BRACKET_PAIRS = { '{' => '}', '[' => ']', '(' => ')' }
BRACKET_REGEX = /#{BRACKET_PAIRS.to_a.flatten.map { |v| Regexp.escape(v) }.join('|')}/

def valid?(string)
  brackets = string.scan(BRACKET_REGEX)
  return(false) unless brackets.size > 0 # this line is added

  while brackets.size > 0
    first = brackets.shift
    last = brackets.pop
    return(false) unless BRACKET_PAIRS[first] == last
  end

  return(true)
end
```

As a side note, you'll want to avoid making arrays in loops like you did in your example:

```
string.each_char do |c|
  match_count += 1 if [ '[', '{', '(' ].include?(c)
  match_count -= 1 if [ ']', '}', ')' ].include?(c)
end
```

This code will create two arrays and 6 strings per character in your `string` variable. This is very inefficient and you'll use a lot more RAM and CPU than necessary. You want to at the very least make those two arrays outside the loop, since they don't change, and ideally even make them a constant so that you don't even make them every time you call the method. Make them one when your program boots up and use it forever. Little things like this actually make a really big difference, especially when used in a loop.

Comment: Good call about not splitting string into an array, I tend to forget about using `#each_char` over `#chars`.

Comment: @MarcinKołodziej I actually didn't use `each_char` in my answer either, though you're totally right, using `each_char` is more efficient than `chars.each`, since it doesn't make a new array. I recently learned about `each_key` and `each_value` in a hash as well, which is again nice as opposed to `keys.each` or `values.each` because again you aren't making pointless arrays. The more work you can save the garbage collector, the better. Especially if your Ruby version is older.

Comment: You didn't, but I did and I went back to correct that. Anyway, it's nice to see someone caring about not instantiating multiple temporary data structures in Ruby.

Comment: Yeah! There's a lot of little tricks like this that I've been learning and they actually add up if you get into good practice with them. Most times, it doesn't take much change to write code very efficiently. We've started using RuboCop (https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop) at work, and it makes suggestions to you about simple changes (like I just mentioned) to improve performance. It's really helpful.

Comment: RuboCop is definitely nice, but be careful about it sometimes, especially when it comes to performance, this particular issue comes to mind: https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop/issues/3633

Comment: Yeah, we definitely fight the "style" cops sometimes, though I didn't realize `.zero?` was slower than `== 0`. Thanks for the info!

Comment: This yields `valid? "[a]{b[c{d}e]fg}" #=> false` for both methods, yet the braces, brackets and parentheses in this string are are balanced.

Comment: I see. I thought it was just supposed to be nesting, such as `a[{b[c{d}e]fg}]`. Adding support for that is doable, but more complicated.

Comment: So is it safe to say that your also want "([a]{[b](c){[d(e)]}(f){g}})" to be true?

Comment: I would think so. If my understanding of the question is correct you can see why pusing and popping a stack works well here.

Answer (score 1):

```
CLOSE_TO_OPEN = { ']'=>'[', '}'=>'{', ')'=>'(' }

def valid?(str)
  str.each_char.with_object([]) do |c,stack|
    case c
    when '[', '{', '('
      stack << c
    when ']', '}', ')'
      return false unless stack.pop == CLOSE_TO_OPEN[c]
    end
  end.empty?
end

valid? "[a]{b[c{d}e]fg}" #=> true
valid? "[a]{b[c{d]e}fg}" #=> false
```

The behaviour of the method can be seen by adding some `puts` statements.

```
def valid?(str)
  str.each_char.with_object([]) do |c,stack|
    puts "c=#{c}, stack=#{stack}"
    case c
    when '[', '{', '('
      stack << c
      puts "  stack after 'stack << #{c}' = #{stack}"
    when ']', '}', ')'
      print "  stack.pop (#{stack.last||'nil'})==CLOSE_TO_OPEN[#{c}] " +
            "(#{CLOSE_TO_OPEN[c]})=>"
      puts stack.last == CLOSE_TO_OPEN[c] ? "true, so continue" :
        "false, so return false"
      return false unless stack.pop == CLOSE_TO_OPEN[c]
    end
  end.tap { |stack| puts "At end, '#{stack}.empty?` (#{stack.empty?})" }.empty?
end
```

```
valid? "[a]{b[c{d}e]fg}"
c=[, stack=[]
  stack after 'stack << [' = ["["]
c=a, stack=["["]
c=], stack=["["]
  stack.pop ([)==CLOSE_TO_OPEN[]] ([)=>true, so continue
c={, stack=[]
  stack after 'stack << {' = ["{"]
c=b, stack=["{"]
c=[, stack=["{"]
  stack after 'stack << [' = ["{", "["]
c=c, stack=["{", "["]
c={, stack=["{", "["]
  stack after 'stack << {' = ["{", "[", "{"]
c=d, stack=["{", "[", "{"]
c=}, stack=["{", "[", "{"]
  stack.pop ({)==CLOSE_TO_OPEN[}] ({)=>true, so continue
c=e, stack=["{", "["]
c=], stack=["{", "["]
  stack.pop ([)==CLOSE_TO_OPEN[]] ([)=>true, so continue
c=f, stack=["{"]
c=g, stack=["{"]
c=}, stack=["{"]
  stack.pop ({)==CLOSE_TO_OPEN[}] ({)=>true, so continue
At end, '[].empty?` (true)
  #=> true
```

```
valid? "[a]{b[c{d]e}fg}"
c=[, stack=[]
  stack after 'stack << [' = ["["]
c=a, stack=["["]
c=], stack=["["]
  stack.pop ([)==CLOSE_TO_OPEN[]] ([)=>true, so continue
c={, stack=[]
  stack after 'stack << {' = ["{"]
c=b, stack=["{"]
c=[, stack=["{"]
  stack after 'stack << [' = ["{", "["]
c=c, stack=["{", "["]
c={, stack=["{", "["]
  stack after 'stack << {' = ["{", "[", "{"]
c=d, stack=["{", "[", "{"]
c=], stack=["{", "[", "{"]
  stack.pop ({)==CLOSE_TO_OPEN[]] ([)=>false, so return false
  #=> false
```